# How should I structure the SQL database for a novel reading site?

Tags: mysql

I'm building a site where users will be able to read and save their progress for any book on the site (bookmark the chapter last read). What's a good way to structure the users table? Should I make a column for each book to store the current bookmark number or is there a much better way?

EDIT:

Thanks a lot for the example and rating suggestion hank! What do you think about this:

**Users**

- User's ID
- Username
- Email
- Hashed Password

**Books**

- Book's ID
- Book Title
- *Chapter number*
- *Chapter content*

**Book Rating**

- Book
- Overall Rating

**Book Genre**

- Book
- Genre

**Book Progress and Rating**

- User
- Book
- Chapter
- Status
- *Rating*

Is this method of storing individual chapters a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For normalization, I would do something like this;

**Users**

- ID
- username
- etc

**Books**

- ID
- title
- etc

**Genres**

- ID
- Genre

**Book Genre**

- Book
- Genre

**Book Progress**

- User
- Book
- Chapter/Page
- Status (Wishlist, Not started yet, Reading, Finished)

This allows for multiple users tracking progress for the same book, which opens up for suggestions on what book a user should read next, based on what others have read.

Maybe you would want to allow the users to rate a book (or even a chapter, who know?!) Keep it normalized, that's  the key!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example and rating suggestion! What do you think about this:

**Users**

+ User's ID
+ Username
+ Email
+ Hashed Password

**Books**

+ Book's ID
+ Book Title
+ *Chapter number*
+ *Chapter content*

**Book Rating**

+ Book
+ Overall Rating

**Book Genre**

+ Book
+ Genre

**Book Progress and Rating**

+ User
+ Book
+ Chapter
+ Status
+ *Rating*


Is this method of storing individual chapters a good idea? EDIT: Seems I cannot put bullets in comments, I updated the main question

Comment: I would have a new table for Chapter (if you want to store this too, it can be a little too much imo)